# How to release Mongo DB in production environment?

Tags: mongodb, database

I've been playing around with Mongo DB recently in my spare time (for work I normally use relational DBs, or more recently RDF triple stores) and I have a question that has been bothering me. When you have developed an application that uses Mongo DB and it now needs to be deployed in the production environment, what is the recommended process for releasing the database?

To be clear, I'm not talking about simply deploying an existing database on a server, I'm more interested in how to initially create a database in a state that is usable for the application.

So for example, with an SQL database you might have a set of scripts that create the database, create all the required tables, initialise the tables with any required data, set up access rights, views, etc.

What is bothering me is that with Mongo if the database, tables etc don't exist when you query them then they are created automatically. However I'm aware that it's possible to write Mongo scripts in JS to perform sequences of Mongo commands.

So in short, I guess the question is do you need to go to the trouble of writing these setup and initialisation scripts, or is it simply a case of installing Mongo and pointing your application to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have to do much less to set up mongo for production than a SQL database. And in many instances there's nothing that needs to be done but to point your application at an empty mongo instance.

You will sometimes want to seed certain collections with data. There are numerous approaches for doing this. You can use mongodump and mongorestore (they can work on individual collections or an entire database). You can load json files through your mongo driver, or via a higher level wrapper like mongoose.

You may also want to create indexes on certain collections. Higher level wrappers like mongoose will do this automatically, but you may want to write a script that calls ensureIndex with the indexes you want on your collections that you run from the command line. It doesn't matter of you have no documents in the database.

Comment: Ok great, so basically there's no need to create the database/collections unless they have to be seeded with some initial data or have some specific configuration applied. I guess this seeding and configuration would be done by script or is generally done by cloning what you need from an existing database?

Comment: Apologies, ignore the last question, I re-read your answer and it covers it well.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways I'd recommend in how to deploy MangoDB. The best would be to copy the db data directory with a single tar command. Then take the .tar file and exact it on your production environment. Make sure DB Versions are compatible.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it's useful to an extent, but please refer to the second paragraph of my question. I'm more interested in creating and initialising the database in the production environment, as opposed to importing a dump of a pre-prod or dev database

Comment: have you tried a db dump and import on your prod db? it should have all your app settings.

Comment: This is currently just for a pet project of mine, so I only have one database. I'm just trying to adjust to the Mongo paradigm and get it straight in my head. The question is more related to reliably creating a database with no data specific to that application instance (or any other) and is ready for use by the application. Just an export/import will only do that if you already have an instance in the state you want. Although, creating something like that and just installing clones is as good an answer as any!